# i18n 1.4: Use of undefined constant MENU_PREFERRED_LINK

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

Has anyone run into trouble following i18n update to version 1.4? My site crashes badly with multiple notices about use of undefined constant MENU_PREFERRED_LINK. This is caused by Menu translation submodule.

Submitted a [bug report](http://drupal.org/node/1432744) but thought maybe someone found out a cure for that.

Comment: As this is describing a bug in an existing module, this question is off-topic as per FAQ. It is also too localized, as once the bug is fixed on the module, the question is not anymore of interest for future readers. As it is essentially asking "Has anybody else noticed this?" it is also asking for opinions, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone bumps into that: apparently the i18n module is not compatible with Drupal 7.9. After I updated the core to 7.12 - all problems went away.
Haven't seen the module to mention a particular D7 release as a requirement, though.

Comment: indeed, I had this problem on 2 of my websites that both have a new i18n install. I upgraded both websites from 7.9 to 7.12 and all errors went way on both websites. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer Artur.
I know, this literally makes me go crazy.
Unfortunately, when I log in to my site, when I try to click anything, from the content and up to any function of admin panel, such as modules or configuration, I just keep on getting the same error message, I am not able to perform any cache clearing on disabling the modules, error prevents me to do anything. I would like to find the solution, because if I not, I would have to begin again from scratch.

Comment: I'm not myself a Drupal expert yet, but what I would do is to erase the i18n folder from the modules folder and see what happens. Hopefully someone could come up with more expertise. Updating of the modules seems to be a roulette and I start to appreciate db backups before running any update. Even when you're not live with your site, it just bloody hurts to lose the time.